# Make pdf editable in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net

I have a PDF  or Image . in this i can write something, draw line , high light sentences then download it .

how to Achieve this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Well PDF and Images are two different things.

I know it's poor advice but you should really do a quick web search for ".net pdf library". You will find dozens of paid and free code libraries for creating and manipulating PDF documents with plenty of very good documentation on how to use them.

Similarly for Images there are also many, many .net libraries for doing image manipulation.